# Where can I find information about the effects of GUIs

Tags: gui-design, research, information

I need resources for information on the effects of the creation of GUIs for PCs. When I started looking up information on GUIs, but I mostly found the computers that first started using GUIs, the changes made in GUIs and how to make GUIs.

I'm doing an essay, and I need resources for some effects it had on people, and factual evidence to back up some of the statements. (statistics on users, effects on system response, effects on sales, etc.) Really, just something that would stop my essay from being a statement of my opinion. If you own or know of a website that has information on this topic it would be much appreciated.

Comment: The question is really, really broad, and in a world of specialization it's hard to answer. It also seems like you might be looking at this backwards. I'd look up history of GUI resources and read through them to determine some effects to talk about.
If you have specific questions, like 'what have been the effects of of GUIs in the workplace' or 'in art' or some other constraining domain, you'll likely be able to find people who've written about that kind of specific focus.

Comment: What kind of effects, short term/long term, activation effects/changes in behaviour or changes in lifestyle and opinions? Please narrow down a bit what you're looking for. This might be a better question to ask on Chat.

Comment: I'd suggest you look at GUI's in contrast to what already existed, ie 'Command Line' interfaces such as DOS.  The disadvantage of DOS was that it depended on people remembering (which they are poor at) rather than recognising - as in a GUI (which people are much better at)

Comment: You should talk with the guys over at http://www.elementaryos.org/ they're doing a great job introducing usability to linux. Ask what their secrets are. One thing is for sure: consistency.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.amanda.com/joomla_uploads/whitepapers/AM+A_ROIWhitePaper_20Apr0%201.pdf

Perhaps better search keywords are what you need also I suspect you want research papers rather than blogs. Note "GUI" typically refers to a technical component, try "usability".

http://scholar.google.co.nz/scholar?hl=en&q=usability+importance